# How to install plugins in Qt Creator?

Tags: windows, qt-creator

The following link has a gallery for useful Qt creator plugins.

https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Creator_Plug-in_Gallery

But unfortunately, I don't know how to install any of them. For example, how to install artistic code style plugin?

Does Qt creator has a plugin manager like Eclipse that facilitates adding plugins through it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find instructions for installation at the bottom of the webpage of Artistic Code Style plugin:

> Quick
>
> Move the downloaded zip/tar.bz2 archive to the root directory of
>   Qt Creator and extract it. After a restart of Qt Creator all should
>   work.

Looks like plugins can be found under `.\QtCreator\lib\qtcreator\plugins` so if you want to install a plugin you just need to copy the files of the plugin (one `dll` and one `pluginspec`) there and (re)start Qt Creator.

Comment: I can't find .\QtCreator folder. but in the above link it's mentioned to run "locate Welcome.pluginspec" and copy the plugin to that location. Well, that works. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Bill This plugin doesn't seem to come with a pluginspec file? https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtc-cppcheck/files/bin/3.6.0/ Is that a required thing?

Comment: @DavidDoria Unfortunately I do not know. I would try to install it without the missing pluginspec file and see if it works.